# using javascript how would I change this to display on page load?

Tags: javascript, css

The html attribute I am trying to change is:

```
<li class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-tools" id="menu-tools" style="display: none; ">
```

Thank you,

I know it is not detailed, but I could not think of anything else I needed to say.

Comment: When you say on page load, do you mean once the document is ready or when all the content (including images) has finishing downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ $("#menu-tools").show();  });
```

`$("#menu-tools").hide();` and `$("#menu-tools").show();` should do the trick instead of using inline css. This requires jQuery.

Comment: Note that this requires jQuery, which the question does not explicitly specify. (And they use inline CSS in the background, by the way.)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. Added it to the response.

Answer (score 0):

Since it has an ID, go ahead and refer to it by ID using `document.getElementById`:

```
onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('menu-tools').style.display = 'block';
};
```